# Как прервать/остановить горутину?

Tags: golang

**Как мне остановить горутину в** **Golang?** У меня код каждые 5 секунд обновляет страницу и если находит различия в `html тексте`то выдает что в тексте было изменено 200 с чем-то символов и т.д и пишет так постоянно уже не прерываясь из-за чего я не могу продолжить дальше проверку на изменения, мне нужно остановить горутину проверить другой процесс и только после этого запустить вновь нужную мне горутину. Нашел код на зарубежном форуме:

```
package main

import "sync"
import "net/http"
import "fmt"
func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)

    ch := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        for {
            foo, ok := <- ch
            if !ok {
                response, err := http.Get("http://golang.org")
                if err != nil {
                    fmt.Println("error")
                } else {
                    fmt.Println(response.Body, response.Header)
                }
                wg.Done()
                return
            }
            println(foo)
        }
    }()
    ch <- 1
    ch <- 2

    close(ch)

    wg.Wait()
}
```

Непонятны 2 момента, это с ch <- 2 почему число выводит два раза, а запрос подается один раз. И как мне эту горутину перебить другой горутиной и потом вновь запустить?

Comment: Отправьте этой рутине сигнал о завершении через канал.

Comment: @GreenDragon можно пожалуйста пример, нашел на зарубежном форуме пример с "sync" но это все как-то длинно и запутано. Я ничего не понял, что и как действует. Можно пожалуйста пример с подробностями. Буду очень благодарен!

Comment: Чтобы запустить и проверить работоспособность кода с зарубежного форума не нужно знать иностранный язык. Будет лучше если вы возьмете книгу по программированию на Go или зададите конкретный вопрос о той части кода, который вам не понятен.

Comment: @GreenDragon как я читал это "чистый выход из приложения", а не закрытия горутины